# Prevent user from deleting default value on TextInput

Tags: javascript, react-native

I recently just started learning react-native, and i encounter a problem where i'm trying to make a simple text box for user to type their phone number with predefined default value in the front (country/iso code phone number). I have tried using `react-native-phone-input` and basic textinput. how can i prevent the user from deleting the default value??

The codes goes something like this

```
<PhoneInput
          ref={(ref) => {
              this.phone = ref;
          }}
          allowZeroAfterCountryCode={false}
          value= "+44"
          initialCountry='uk'
          onPressFlag={this.onPressFlag}
          onChangePhoneNumber={(number) => this.setState({phone: number})}
  />
```

Comment: Any solution so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that controls input:

```
onChangePhoneNumber={(number) => this.onChangeInut(number)}
```

implementation:

```
onChangeInput = (number) => {
   if(number.substring(0,3) == '+44'){
      this.setState({phone: number})
   }
}
```

Comment: i try this with and `else` condition that goes something like `this.setState({phone: "+44"})` and log the phone state, the value doesnt go below '+44' but the value in the textbox still got deleted

Comment: Try it here: 
https://snack.expo.io/?session_id=snack-session-gkdJPIK7x